# Questions About This Curve in $ \mathbb{P}^{3}_{k} $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ k $ be an algebraically closed field.

Consider the map $$ \varphi : \mathbb{P}^{1}_{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}_{k}, $$
$$ (t_{0}:t_{1}) \mapsto (t^{3}_{0}:t^{2}_{0}t_{1}:t_{0}t^{2}_{1}:t^{3}_{1}). $$

According to Klaus Hulek's Elementary Algebraic Geometry, $ C:= \varphi(\mathbb{P}^{1}_{k}) $ is a projective variety given by

$$ C =  \Bigg\lbrace (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}:x_{3}) \in \mathbb{P}^{3}_{k} \Bigg|\ \text{rank}\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{0} & x_{1} & x_{2}  \\
x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3}
\end{pmatrix} \leq 1 \Bigg\rbrace $$

My first question is why this is the image of $ \varphi. $

Furthermore, the author notes that $ C = Q_{1} \cap Q_{2} \cap Q_{3}, $ where
$$ Q_{1} = \lbrace (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}) \in \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}| \; x_{0}x_{2}-x^{2}_{1} = 0 \rbrace $$ 
$$ Q_{2} = \lbrace (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}) \in \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}| \; x_{0}x_{3}-x_{1}x_{2} = 0 \rbrace  $$
$$ Q_{3} = \lbrace (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}) \in \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}| \; x_{1}x_{3}-x^{2}_{2} = 0 \rbrace. $$

I notice the defining polynomial of each of these quadrics is the determinant of a minor of the matrix above, and I don't know why. This may be an obvious thing, but it is quite interesting to me.

Comment: You may search "d-uple embedding"

Comment: The rank condition is equivalent to the simultaneous vanishing of the determinants of the three minors. It's easy to check that taking $x_0 = t_0^3,...,x_3 = t_1^3$, the three quadratic equations hold. With a little more work you can show that any point in the intersection of the three quadrics is in the image of $\varphi$.